# Implementar Materialize-css en Next Js

Tags: javascript

Hola Comunidad estoy tratando de implementar **Materialize-css** en **NextJs** pero al usar componentes como el **SideNav** no inicializan he tratado de integrar el *script js* de varias formas pero ninguna sin éxito gracias de antemano ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporando
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`
en  la etiqueta Head de Nextjs , algo simple que no se como se me pudo escapar espero sirva de aporte a la comunidad :)